# jQuery / Bootstrap carousel container responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a quick wireframe and to help illustrate what it is I would like to accomplish either with twitter bootstrap on its own or with a jQuery plugin. If there is any way to also build it with pure html5 and css3 that would be cool. [image]

The thumbnails can be scrolled horizontally and snap in to place so that the left thumbnail is always in full view. The user can then click a thumbnail to reveal its carousel content.

There will be 2 break points for mobile and tablet. Each breakpoint will change the width of the container div that house the thumbmnails. This means that on smaller devices there will be more horizontal scrolling. Scrolling on tablet and smart phone will be by touch.

The carousel can also be touch swiped.

If someone could please point me in the right direction that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest place to start is probably http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/.  I have used it quite regularly and in particular it is fully responsive so will remove the need for specific break points. I've also found that it is quite easy to play around with the code should you want to customize it more than normal or shrink it down in size a bit,
Hope that helps,
Dan